# APK failing to build release because of bundleReleaseJsAndAssets

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

Running ./gradlew AssembleRelease or trying to generate a signed release APK via Android Studio both throw error in npx.cmd on bundleReleaseJsAndAssets, bolded in code below.

Have tried enabling and disabling Hermes, cleaning, stopping daemons and rebuilding the project over 10 times from Android Studio, VS Code, and from an Admin Powershell. Running the app in debug mode in an emulator works fine.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
>   warning: the transform cache was reset.
>   Loading dependency graph, done.
>   info Writing bundle output to:, C:\Users\juan.castelli\Desktop\master
>   info Writing sourcemap output to:, C:\Users\juan.castelli\Desktop\master
>   info Done writing bundle output
>   info Done writing sourcemap output
>   info Copying 34 asset files
>   error EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\juan.castelli\Desktop\master'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
>   Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\juan.castelli\Desktop\master'
>   Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   **What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
>   Process 'command 'npx.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1**
>   BUILD FAILED in 1m 58s
>   151 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 149 up-to-date

Several tasks from the npm packages give NO-SOURCE for each of these tasks: compileReleaseRenderscript, packageReleaseRenderscript, compileReleaseAidl, but I am not sure what that means.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I get the same error with me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering my own question: In the main folder do
`npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`.

Then do `cd Android`

and then  `./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`

That will correctly generate a release APK with no errors in my experience, putting the APK in android/app/build/outputs/apk/release

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps :

```
npm i -g react-native-cli
```

then run

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```

will extract the apk in the path `android\app\build\outputs\apk\release`

Comment: Marked as correct because it did generate an assemble APK correctly, thank you.    

May I ask a couple questions though? What does the -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets do? And why is the APK generated "old"? As in, it's a past version of my app. Like the changes haven't saved. In other words, your solution builds an APK but it's not the same app that runs as the one when I run react-native run-android directly.